# load form using AJAX will loose form and values after a failed submission

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax

I have a PHP page that loads several parts of a form using AJAX. For instance, first check if the user is already registered, if so the script loads (with AJAX) the rest of the form. The form will not be submited using AJAX what can be a problem when the user submits the form (without AJAX) - imagine there are some errors - the form will loose all values.
I'm wondering if CSS hiding part of the form and after the successful login use JS to display the rest of the form, would be better.

Here some code:

```
<form action="some_action.php">
    Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email"> <br />
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password"> <br />
    <button id="vrf_login">Verificar</button>

    <div id="rest_form">

    </div>
</form>
```

AJAX:
- CHECK login: if email and password matches then 
- LOAD the form for div with id "rest_form"
  (it is in another file, for instance:

```
<input type="text" name="place" id="place">
<input type="text" name="age" id="age">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
```

)

The problem is if I submit the form (without AJAX) and there are errors I will loose the form loaded with AJAX

**EDIT (again)**

Thank you all for your constructive suggestions:
The solution I adopted is close to the first Alkis's suggestion:

- almost all the form is hidden (CSS)
- after some logic choices the (part of the) form is turned visible (jQuery) - to "remember" what parts should be visible in case of submission failed (server side  validation) some session variables hold the information  (AJAX) - and then, after the submission (failed) use jQuery to restore the prior form structure  (get the session variables with JS this way:  `var xpto = "<?php echo $_SESSION['prior_xpto']; ?>" ;` )
- the fields of the form will remember theirs values (with PHP)

Comment: Would it be viable to make the validations on the client and only if all the data are valid, proceed with the submission as you intended to.

Comment: Is ajax really loosening the form values? or is it losing them?

Comment: @alkis But wouldn't be a risk to make the validations only on the client (and not server side validation)?

Comment: @Phil_1984_ I only used ajax to load the form and submit the form using PHP (without AJAX). After submit / failed sever side validation I loose all the form (loaded with AJAX) and values already filled

Comment: You can still have the validations on the server for extra security and you take as a given that the user will lose the data if something exceptional happens, but in most cases you have the desired outcome. Another thing would be to make the form to have default values of the parameters that you receive on the server. On the initial load, those values would be the default ones (empty, or otherwise), and when the user submits the form, if something happens you return to the same page, but now, those variables have the values of the user.

Comment: @bito_ I dont mean to be rude but this will probably be useful to you.  http://www.ross.net/notes/loose.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 options.

1. Stop loading the whole form by ajax. Hide it with css and show it if the the conditions are met. If the page is shown after some validation error, just show it (change the css inline or give it a different class)
2. Have a condition and every time the page loads check if it is a first load or if the page is shown after some validation error occured. If the latter is true then load again the form with ajax. This condition can be a hidden field that takes its value from the server and you check it on the client every time you serve the page.
3. The second solution can be done on the server too. Have the condition be checked on the server. If it's a first load, then don't populate the form and let it be populated from ajax as you do now. If it's after a validation error then pre-populate the form. It's just an if/else clause.

Comment: For name and email there is no problem but I have other fields loaded with AJAX. After the submission these (last) loaded  fields will desapear.

Comment: Name and email, are just examples. They are not your name and email. My suggestion is for the fields that get the values from ajax.

Comment: There aren't the values but the form that is loaded with ajax. The fields loaded with ajax will disappear after the submission.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide some codes for your question, but i guess your problem is sending result using a button with "submit" type !

if you have a form like this:

```
 <form>
 <inputs ...>  
 <input type="submit" value="Send data" onclick="SendDataUsingAjax()" >
 </form>
```

after clicking on submit all values on input will reset regardless of what your ajax function is doing. to fix this problem you only need to change type="submit" to type="button".